# Filtering and sorting by a calculated field

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, t-sql

I have an SQL query I'm trying to convert into LINQ for C# but I can't work out how to sort and filter on a calculated field.

```
from p in PartRevisions
where (p.Inactive == 0)
where (p.LastCost != p.AvgCost) || (p.LastCost != p. StandardCost) 
select new {
    PartID = p.PartID,
    Desc = p.ShortDescription,
    AvgCost = p.AvgCost,
    LastCost = p.LastCost,
    last_avg = 100* ( (p.AvgCost > p.LastCost) ? 
     ((p.LastCost > 0) ? (p.AvgCost - p.LastCost) / p.LastCost : (decimal?)null):
     ((p.AvgCost> 0) ? (p.LastCost - p.AvgCost ) / p.AvgCost : (decimal?)null))
}
```

The query executes ok but I need to add a where clause and a sort clause to the calculated field last_avg
ie where last_avg > 10
orderby last_avg descending.

This is the same query in SQL

```
SELECT  PartID, PartRevisionID, LastCost, AverageCost, 
CASE WHEN LastCost < AvgCost THEN (AvgCost - LastCost) / NULLIF (LastCost, 0) ELSE (LastCost - AvgCost) / NULLIF (AvgCost, 0) END AS Last_Avg, 
FROM  PartRevisions
WHERE (LastCost <> AvgCost OR LastCost <> StandardCost) AND (Inactive == 0) 
ORDER BY Last_Avg DESC
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is working. For those wanting to know I found the answer here.
[Calculating Intermediate Values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693155.aspx)

```
from p in PartRevisions
let last_avg = 100* ( (p.AvgCost > p.LastCost) ? 
     ((p.LastCost > 0) ? (p.AvgCost - p.LastCost) / p.LastCost : (decimal?)null):
     ((p.AvgCost> 0) ? (p.LastCost - p.AvgCost ) / p.AvgCost : (decimal?)null))

where (p.ImrInactive == 0)
where (p.LastCost != p.AvgCost) || (p.LastCost != p.ImrStandardMaterialCost) 
where (last_avg > 10) || (last_avg == null)
orderby last_avg descending
select new {
    PartID = p.ImrPartID,
    Desc = p.ImrShortDescription,
    AvgCost = p.AvgCost,
    LastCost = p.LastCost,
    Last_Avg = last_avg
}
```

Comment: It should be pointed out that while `let` provides a convenient syntax, if you look at the SQL generated, those calculated fields are calculated each time the `let` value is used.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
(from p in PartRevisions
where (p.Inactive == 0)
where (p.LastCost != p.AvgCost) || (p.LastCost != p. StandardCost) 
select new {
    PartID = p.PartID,
    Desc = p.ShortDescription,
    AvgCost = p.AvgCost,
    LastCost = p.LastCost,
    last_avg = 100* ( (p.AvgCost > p.LastCost) ? 
     ((p.LastCost > 0) ? (p.AvgCost - p.LastCost) / p.LastCost : (decimal?)null):
     ((p.AvgCost> 0) ? (p.LastCost - p.AvgCost ) / p.AvgCost : (decimal?)null))
})
.OrderByDescending(pr => pr.last_avg);
```

Comment: I'm using LINQPad5 to debug in. Adding that statement gives. does not contain a definition for 'last_avg' and no extension method 'last_avg' accepting a first argument of type ... error

Comment: @labnet Did you copy it exactly? It works perfectly fine locally with LINQPad. I would imagine one of the brackets is out of place.

Comment: I double checked but still no go. Note you didn't include the where clause I also needed. Thanks for contributing so quickly though. I have posted below what I think the answer is.